# Drupal 7 Get Comments Of Node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there an easy way to get the comments of a node programmatically in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the function [comment_get_thread()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_get_thread/7), it may be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write a code then you can override the node with The panel's node template and by creating a variant in it you can add comment thread in the variant. And I think it is very easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can use the below code to get all the comments of a node using node ID

```
$nid = 2; // node ID
    $comments = db_select('comment')
              ->fields('comment', array('name','subject'))
              ->condition('nid', $nid, '=')
              ->execute()
              ->fetchAssoc();
    foreach($comments as $comment) {
        print your comments here
    }
```

In Drupal 6 you can use the [comment_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_render/6) ;